Fantasy Movie: erection experiment, people divided into classes
I watched this on TV as a kid, early 90s or late 80s. I can't remember the plot but only a few scenes.
There was a big tree and a floating thing (a floating land maybe) that carries people between some places.
There was a scene where a group of people conducting an experiment on a naked man standing, by showing some erotic photographs to him on a big screen. After a time, man starts to stare at one of the female observers and without seeing we understand that he gets an erection.
There were some different group of people with different 'classes'. There was a scene that they banish someone from a class to a lower class for punishment.

Could it possibly Zardoz, one of our most requested movies in ID, yet again...?

It definitely is, thank you :) I'm very surprised that it is a well known movie.

As identified by Walt in the comments (and subsequently confirmed by the OP), this is Zardoz, a 1974 film starring Sean Connery and Charlotte Rampling.
The scene you describe is the 6th item on the list here (note: the video clip is before the list item).
As you say, there are different classes of people in the film. From Wikipedia's plot description:

In a future post-apocalypse Earth in the year 2293, the human population is divided into the immortal "Eternals" and mortal "Brutals". The Brutals live in a wasteland, growing food for the Eternals, who live apart in "the Vortex", leading a luxurious but aimless existence on the grounds of a country estate. The connection between the two groups is through Brutal Exterminators, who kill and terrorize other "Brutals" at the orders of a huge flying stone head called Zardoz, which supplies them with weapons in exchange for the food they collect.

